# Does iOS App Slicing remove unneeded parts of universal static libraries?

Tags: ios, app-thinning

I have an iOS project that links to a universal static library (.a file), supporting both armv7 and arm64 architectures. When the app binary is sliced as part of [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html), does that process remove the unnecessary architectures from within the .a file? Or do I need to provide separate .a files for each architecture somehow to get this benefit in binary size (and if so, how do I do this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinning should only link required archs.

From another static lib (includes link to Apple's doc on how to get App Thinning report):

> The IndoorAtlas iOS SDK is a static library compiled for multiple architectures. Only required architectures are linked to the Thinned application. You may test the thinning results locally with these instruction: [Testing Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) - "The App Thinning Size Report file contains a summary of the sizes of all variants and the app-thinning.plist file contains more details."

Unlink the library, get baseline App Thinning Report. Link the library, get new report and compare them both.